# Can we help you moderate more?

Tags: discussion, moderation

[Community elected moderators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEysB.jpg) on this site are very active. This is mostly due to a fact that our rules do require a lot of moderation.

However, this does not mean that *everything* needs to be done by moderators, and in particular I'm thinking of:

- welcoming users and introducing them to the rules of the site
- editing questions so they have the correct tags, grammar and typography
- editing answers so they appropriately include citations or links to sources
- engaging users on meta and explaining the site rules to them.

I believe these things can be done, and will be best done, by you -- the community. We'd very much like to see more involvement. I understand we have a lot of users who avoid posting much because, let's say it, [posting here is difficult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW4tK.gif), and moderating even more so, but I don't think the same could be said about [the activities above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zcr0y.jpg). In fact, it could be a great way of gaining more confidence and throwing your hat in the arena.

How can we help you moderate more?

Comment: What's the yellow and brown thing in the second photo? O_o

Comment: To be honest, I think part of the problem is having access to the comment macros that other users have so the "Welcome to the site" can be automatically inserted.

Comment: @rjzii That's a user script you can download and install on your browser. It's not a mod-only tool. It's called [proforma](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) and the auto comments I used are  [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sklivvz/3497867/raw/proforma.json)